# Django fails to model legacy database with inspectdb

Tags: django, geodjango, django-2.2

I have a currently empty **Geodjango** app set up - I am connected to my **Postgis** database in which I have a table named **aadf** that I am attempting to create a model from. I am using **inspectdb** to do this.

I get the following error message:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
# Unable to inspect table 'aadf'
# The error was: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'
# Unable to inspect table 'auth_group'
# The error was: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'
# Unable to inspect table 'auth_group_permissions'
# The error was: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'

** This error message repeats for multiple other tables that Django has created **
```

The connection to the database evidently seems fine as it is able to pick up the relevant table name. That said, it also seems to be trying to inspect the other tables Django has created in the database such as 'auth_group' and 'auth_group_permissions'.

Comment: What is your Django version?

Comment: I'm using django 2.2

Comment: You can inspect [just one table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27163702/how-do-i-inspectdb-1-table-from-database-which-contains-1000-tables).

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I still get "# The error was: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'" when only doing it on the relevant table.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I got this error and found that it was caused by using psycopg2 version 2.8 (or 2.8.1) -- downgrading to 2.7.7 made it go away. This is on Windows 10 with Django 2.2.

**Edit:** I see now that there's a fix in the pipeline for Django 2.2 to support psycopg2 2.8.

**Edit (5/1/2019):** Django 2.2.1 is out today with a fix adding support for psycopg2 2.8.

Comment: Thank you so so much for this. Project was at a complete standstill and wouldn't have been able to work this out.

EDIT: I used the following command to downgrade psycopg2 
'pip install psycopg2==2.7.7 --force-reinstall'

Comment: What is the bug# for this? Would be helpful to track the version with the fix!

Comment: FWIW: also pip of psycopg2-2.8.5-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl with Django 1.11 worked