# KeyError: 'force_color' error while runing inspectdb in Django

Tags: django, django-models, inspectdb

I'm trying to execute inspected command with the exclusion of some tables in Django 
I've found this question: [How do I inspectdb 1 table from database which Contains 1000 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27163702/how-do-i-inspectdb-1-table-from-database-which-contains-1000-tables)  similar to mine but the problem is when I run the same code i get a strange error
script.py

```py
from django.core.management.commands.inspectdb import Command
from django.conf import settings
from SFP_test.settings import DATABASES

if not settings.configured:
    settings.configure()
settings.DATABASES = DATABASES

Command().execute(table_name_filter=lambda table_name: table_name in ('base_table', 'bp_table', ), database='sfp')
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/SFP_crud_test/generateapp.py", line 24, in <module>
    Command().execute(table_name_filter=lambda table_name: table_name in ('base_table', 'bp_table', ), database='sfp')
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/SFP_test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in execute
    if options['force_color'] and options['no_color']:
KeyError: 'force_color'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
python manage.py inspectdb <tableName> --database <DatabaseName> > output.py
```

`output.py` will have your table Model

Additionally, ensure to have your database configured in `settings.py` as following

```
DatabaseName': {
       'NAME': 'DbName',
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
       'HOST': 'HostName',
       'USER': 'user',
       'PORT': 9999,
       'OPTIONS': {
            'sslmode': 'require',
            'sslcert': 'cert',
            'sslkey': 'key',
        }
```